# C++ Resolve circular dependency with inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

Inheritance is making this hard for me to solve.

I am making a chess game where I create an interface `Piece` that will represent shared functions and private members for each chess piece. I create a class for each piece (`Rook`, `Bishop` etc..).

```
chessmen/
bishop.cpp
bishop.h
piece.h

src/
board.cpp
board.h
```

The constructor in my board file is responsible for creating and initializing the board with pointers to a piece object.

```
board[0][0] = new Rook(GameData::BLACK);
board[1][0] = new Knight(GameData::BLACK);
board[2][0] = new Bishop(GameData::BLACK);
board[3][0] = new Queen(GameData::BLACK);
board[4][0] = new King(GameData::BLACK);
board[5][0] = new Bishop(GameData::BLACK);
.
.
.
```

Now I am having issues because in each piece class (bishop.cpp etc..) there is a method called `validMoves` which takes in a `Board` object and coordinates on the board.

```
std::vector<GameData::BoardPosition> Bishop::validMoves(Board &b, BoardPosition src) {
```

Since board references all pieces and the pieces reference the board I am stuck trying to figure out how to alleviate this. I know people say that circular dependencies are a sign of a terrible design but I like that each class is responsible for their own rules - makes for a really clean design, plus allows me to track piece state (`hasBeenMoved`).

Here are my files:

```
http://pastebin.com/1AUhTjHL
http://pastebin.com/31mBTfY1
http://pastebin.com/n4VNT0JH
http://pastebin.com/snUTdJ8p
http://pastebin.com/HjCew9gx
http://pastebin.com/eKA5XmWh
```

Just use a simple:

```
#include "board.h"

int main() {
    Board b;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried forward declaring but it only works when I have the definition and not use it:

**Works**

```
.
.
.
class Board;
.
.
.
test(Board &b);
```

**Does not work**

```
.
.
.
class Board;
.
.
.
test(Board &b) {
    b.getMove(...);
}
```

Comment: Do you think that somebody is going to go through 6 pastebin?

Comment: In your "Does not work" example, the compiler needs more details about class `Board` in order to verify the `getMove` method.  Put your class declaration into a header file and include the file in your source files.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your design so that each piece contains a *position*.  This would allow you to have a container of pieces for each player.  You could even have a graveyard of pieces too.

```
struct Position
{
  unsigned int row;
  unsigned int column;
};

class Piece
{
//...
  Position location; //!< Each piece has a location on the board.
};
```

With this design, you may not need a board object.  You can calculate which move to make by a Piece's position.

The concept follows real word mapping:  A player knows the position of pieces.  A player changes the position of his piece. A conflict occurs when one player's piece has the same location as the other player's piece.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward declare the referenced classes in the header files and then include the class declaration header in the implementation file.

piece.hpp

class board;

piece.cpp

include "board.hpp"

Comment: The piece.h file has board implementation inside of it (it is a small function). So what do I do then?

Comment: Split the files and create one declaration .hpp and one implementation .cpp per class.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Matthews makes a great suggestion. If you are married to your Board concept you can turn it into an interface class (abstract base class with pure virtuals = 0) and derive a ChessBoard class from your Board class. All your pieces would then call the functions through the Board interface.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source files of a project which has the same setup as I.

```
https://github.com/cpluspluscom
```

They solve it by using namespaces and having the declaration of the piece interface inside the board header.